# How to use optional argparse argument and subparsers properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I'm trying to write a little app that can do multiple things depending on arguments specified in argparse.

I use a positional argument (soundfiledir) for file directory which must always be specified, but after that I want to specify arguments based on what I want the app to perform. For example, the -A flag will run a specific set of jobs (python main.py [soundfile path] -A)

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('soundfiledir', type=soundfiledir_format, help = "Specify soundfile directory") #positional argument. must always be provided.
parser.add_argument('-A', '--all', action = "store_true", help = "If this flag is specified, the program will transcribe all the sound files in the sound file directory (with timestamps), and will automatically concatenate files recorded close in time")

if args.all: 
does stuff
```

On top of this, I also use subparsers. For example a subparser called fileconcatenator (python main.py [soundfile path] fileconcatenator) can be specified with some options (python main.py [soundfile path] fileconcatenator -a 15)

```
subparser = parser.add_subparsers(dest = 'command')

fileconcatenator_parser = subparser.add_parser('fileconcatenator', help = "Concatenates sound files together")
group1 = fileconcatenator_parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group1.add_argument('-a','--autoconcat',type = positive_int,  nargs = "?", const = 3, default = None, \
    help="Concatenate audio files recorded close in time. By default any file recorded within 3mns of each other.")
group1.add_argument('-m', '--manconcat', type = list, default = [], \
    help = "Concatenate audio files specified as a list.")

fileconverter_parser = subparser.add_parser('fileconverter',help = "Converts files to 16kHz mono wav")
fileconverter_parser.add_argument('-f', '--filestoconvert', type = list, required=True, default = ["All"], \
    help = "Specify which files to convert.")
```

note: You might notice I have type set as positive_int, this is a user specified type programmed using

```
def positive_int(s):
    try:
        value = int(s)
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(f"Expected positive integer got {s!r}")
    if value <= 0:
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(f"Expected positive integer got {s!r}")
```

In main, I have things set up as following:

```
def main():

if args.all:
    
    do stuff

if args.autoconcat is None:
    pass
else:
   do stuff
```

The problem is, when I run *python main.py [soundfile path] -A* , I get **AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'autoconcat'**

The program still runs (because the if args.autoconcat comes after the if args.all block), but I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong.

Any help greatly appreciated. I will amend the question if you find it unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quote from the Python [argparse docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands):

> Note that the object returned by parse_args() will only contain attributes for
> the main parser and the subparser that was selected by the command line (and not
> any other subparsers). So in the example above, when the a command is specified,
> only the foo and bar attributes are present, and when the b command is specified,
> only the foo and baz attributes are present.

This is exactly your case : You are not invoking the programs subcommand `fileconcatenator`, so the `args` object will not contain the arguments of that subcommand, e.g.  `autoconcat`. You have to check first which subcommand was called. This can be done by having an option common for all subcommands, which is not modifiable by the command-line user. It will be set for each subcommand separately, and when subcommand a is called, this argument will have value a, and when subcommand b is called the argument will have value b. This can be achieve by calling `set_defaults` on each subparser like this:

```py
fileconcatenator_parser = subparser.add_parser('fileconcatenator', help = "Concatenates sound files together")
fileconcatenator_parser.set_defaults(parser_name="fileconcatenator")
# adding some arguments here

fileconverter_parser = subparser.add_parser('fileconverter',help = "Converts files to 16kHz mono wav")
fileconverter_parser.set_defaults(parser_name="fileconverter")
#adding some arguments here
```

and then in main, check first if `parser_name` is fileconverter or fileconcatenator, and check for the arguments based on which subcommand was called.

```py
def main():
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.parser_name == "fileconverter":
        # do something with args.filestoconvert
    elif args.parser_name == "fileconcatenator":
        if args.autoconcat is None:
             pass
        else:
             # do something
```

You may have to call `set_defaults(parser_name="main")` on the main parser
to make it work.